# HERE Map SDK iOS (Lite Edition) Usage in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

This is my View skeleton:

[image]

I have implemented the `HERE Map` for iOS (Lite Edition). I have the `MapViewLite` inside a `UIScrollView`. I want the map view and the remaining `UIView` to scroll simultaneously, but always the `UIScrollView` intercepts all panning events. In HERE Map for iOS (Starter Edition), there is no scrolling issue, but a specific image marker doesn't display. I updated this SDK, and now I experience this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code, so we can see where the issue might be.

Comment: There is no special code.. I just copy and paste HERE Map SDK sample source code. My View looks like this. ViewController -> ScrollView -> View -> MapView and other things. I use the HERE Map SDK for iOS (Lite Edition) v 4.1.2.0 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this first app using the HERE SDK, we want to load one of the default map styles the SDK is shipped with.

```
mapView.mapScene.loadScene(mapStyle: .normalDay, callback: onLoadScene)
```

Please refer below documentation and examples on GITHub to run sample code. Also please share the error if any.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#integrate-the-here-sdk

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-sdk/dev_guide/topics/examples.html